How to generate one ts file Rather than four file during generate component in angular17?
It's any way to create component with cli to select the files of generate component? Or it can only set in the template in editors.
Sometimes, I need to create a simple component and i want to create a standalone component with one ts file,
However, when i use ng g c --standalone AComponent, It will create html, scss, spec, ts four file;

I have see one answer with set
"@schematics/angular:component": {       "spec": false,       "inlineStyle": false,       "inlineTemplate": false,       "prefix": "app",       "styleext": "css"     },  in angular.json

In the angular.json, we can also configure it in @schematics/angular:component.
...
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
       "prefix": "app",
       "style": "scss",
       "skipTests": true,
       "inlineStyle": true,
       "inlineTemplate": true,
  },
  ...


We can also use the arguments to control this.
ng g c test -s -t --skip-tests

ng generate component

--inline-style
Alias: s
Include styles inline in the component.ts file. Only CSS styles can be included inline. By default, an external styles file is created and referenced in the > component.ts file.
Value Type: boolean
Default: false



--inline-template
Alias: t
Include template inline in the component.ts file. By default, an external template file is created and referenced in the component.ts file.
Value Type: boolean
Default: false



--skip-selector
Specifies if the component should have a selector or not.
Value Type: boolean
Default: false



--skip-tests
Do not create "spec.ts" test files for the new component.
Value Type: boolean
Default: false


well, It look hard compare with delete additional file.
ng g c validation --flat=true --inline-style=true --inline-template=true --skipTests=true

@M.H we can also use the aliases so it will be ng g c test -s -t --skip-tests
